# How to generate unique incremental employee code(pattern: E0001, E0002, E0003, ... ) in the INSERT stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to generate unique employee code at a time of inserting a single record in INSERT stored procedure.

First-time procedure call will generate employee code as E0001, the second call will generate E0002, ...

The expected output should look like,

```
EmployeeCode    EmployeeName
-------------------------------
E0001           A
E0002           B
E0003           C
E0004           D
E0005           E
  '             '
  '             '
  '             '
E9999           ZZZ
```

Comment: What is wrong with a simple `identity` column?

Comment: Yes, I do use the identity column. But I just wanted to know how this could be achieved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed a sequence value into a custom-formatted string in a default, and enforce it with a check constraint.  Like this:

```
--drop table if exists Employee
--drop sequence seq_Employee
--go

create sequence seq_Employee
start with 1
increment by 1    
go

CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    EmployeeCode char(5) PRIMARY KEY 
        default 'E' + format((next value for seq_Employee),'0000' )
        check (EmployeeCode like 'E[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'),
    EmployeeName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)    
go

insert into Employee(EmployeeName)
values ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E')

select *
from Employee
```

Outputs

```
EmployeeCode EmployeeName
------------ --------------------------------------------------
E0001        A
E0002        B
E0003        C
E0004        D
E0005        E
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an identity column to create a unique id.  Then use this column for references from other tables.  You can create a code if you like as a computed column:

```
create table employees (
    employeeId int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    employeeName varchar(255),
    employeeCode as (concat('E', format(employeeId, '00000')))
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=702aa27def9c036094f6e221685abd3e) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Use a database sequence number in your procedure to provide you the values. In order to get the value 'E' appended, concatenate 'E' with the sequence number in the query.

[Use this link to understand the concept of database sequence number in sql server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: You could improve your answer by actually showing the OP how to do this - like 2 of the other answers have done.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.Seq  
START WITH 1  
INCREMENT BY 1;  
GO  

DECLARE @T TABLE (
    E_CODE VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    E_Name VARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO @T VALUES (CONCAT('E',FORMAT(NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.SEQ,'0000')),'A')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES (CONCAT('E',FORMAT(NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.SEQ,'0000')),'B')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES (CONCAT('E',FORMAT(NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.SEQ,'0000')),'C')

SELECT * FROM @T
```